# Get the latest record in join linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, max

I have this query

```
return from fitUpExaminationDetails in _ctx.FitUpExaminationDetails
                where fitUpExaminationDetails.FitUpExaminationId == Id
                join joint in _ctx.Joints on fitUpExaminationDetails.JointId equals joint.Id
                join line in _ctx.Lines on joint.LineId equals line.Id
                join fileIsoManager in _ctx.FileIsoManagers on line.Id equals fileIsoManager.LineId

                select new ViewDomainClass.QualityControl.Report.ViewFitupExaminationReport
                {

                    HeatNumber1 = fitUpExaminationDetails.HeatNumber1,
                    HeatNumber2 = fitUpExaminationDetails.HeatNumber2,
                    JointNumber = joint.JointNumber,
                    LineNumber = line.LineNumber,
                    Revision = fileIsoManager.Revision,            
                };
```

My `line` tables can have multi `fileIsoManager` records.So in the select statement  i mean in this part `Revision = fileIsoManager.Revision` i want to show the latest record in `fileIsoManager` table .how can i change this query to do that ?

Comment: Please use proper grammar.and punctuation I gave up halfway through your mess of a paragraph because I just couldn't be bothered to try deciphering it. I'm sure others will do the same.

Comment: @itsme86 so sorry i changed it .

Comment: How to do you know if a revision is the latest one?

Comment: @Kinetic with maximum id

Comment: Is this what you are looking for :`fileIsoManager.OrderByDescending(rev => rev.Id).First()`?  It's kinda hard to answer this question because you give very little detail about your classes.

Comment: @Kinetic yes exactly

Comment: @Kinetic but your code doesn't work for me

Comment: It would be much easier for us if you provided a minimal and working example : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Kinetic the OrderByDescending doesn't solve in the code

Comment: I can't help you if you don't provide a working example.

Comment: @Kinetic comments hint - using "[ M C V E ]" (no spaces) is faster and produce user friendly text - [MCVE].

Comment: I didn't knew.  Is there a reference page for these comment shortcut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, since you didn't provide much details, i've wrote a few classes to show you how to get your latest revision for each line.  Pay attention to the "main" function.

```
// These are a representation of your classes :
public class Line
{
    public int LineId { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue { get; set;}
}

public class Revision
{
    public int RevisionId { get; set; }
    public int LineId { get; set;}  
}

void Main()
{
    // generating some data so we can test the query.
    var lines = new List<Line>() { 
        new Line() { LineId = 1, SomeValue = "Allo!" } 
        };

    var revisions = new List<Revision>() { 
        new Revision() { LineId = 1, RevisionId = 1 }, 
        new Revision() { LineId = 1, RevisionId = 2 }, 
        new Revision() { LineId = 1, RevisionId = 3 }
        };


    var result = (
        from line in lines
        join revision in revisions on line.LineId equals revision.LineId
        group revision by line into grp
        select new
        {
            Line = grp.Key,
            LastRevision = grp.OrderByDescending(rev => rev.RevisionId).FirstOrDefault()
        }
        ).ToList();
}
```

So, basically, you need to group your revisions by line.  In the select part, you can then get the latest revision for each line.

In this example, `result` will contain a dynamic object containing the line id=1 and the revision id = 3.

Going back to your query, it should look like this to get a similar result :

```
return 
    from fitUpExaminationDetails in _ctx.FitUpExaminationDetails
    where fitUpExaminationDetails.FitUpExaminationId == Id
    join joint in _ctx.Joints on fitUpExaminationDetails.JointId equals joint.Id
    join line in _ctx.Lines on joint.LineId equals line.Id
    join fileIsoManager in _ctx.FileIsoManagers on line.Id equals fileIsoManager.LineId
    group fileIsoManager by new { fitUpExaminationDetails, joint, line} into grp
    select new ViewDomainClass.QualityControl.Report.ViewFitupExaminationReport
    {

       HeatNumber1 = grp.Key.fitUpExaminationDetails.HeatNumber1,
       HeatNumber2 = grp.Key.fitUpExaminationDetails.HeatNumber2,
       JointNumber = grp.Key.joint.JointNumber,
       LineNumber = grp.Key.line.LineNumber,
       Revision = grp.OrderByDescending(fileIsoMgr => gileIsoMgr.Id).FirstOrDefault()
    };
```

Comment: So the other fields should be included in groupby

Comment: yeah, you can group by field or the way I've just added to my answer.